# How to use font/google weight in nextjs

Tags: next.js

```
const notoSans = Noto_Sans_EN({
  weight: ['500', '400'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
});
const notoSans = Noto_Sans_EN({
  weight: '400',
  subsets: ['latin'],
});
```

What's the difference between giving weight as an array and a single string in nextjs?

When I apply the above two codes and specify BOLD in the CSS, the weight is different. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide a `weight` to the font you are loading, you are requesting to load that [specific weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).

Each font family comes with a different set of weights, usually 400 being the default, and 700 the default bold.

`weight: '400'` would ask to load the the font with only this weight available.

`weight: ['500', '400']` would make two different weights available, hence the difference in bold texts (500 being bolder than 400).